# Is it possible to do a generic with a DbSet<TVariousClasses>?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

I have the following code where there's a lot of duplication and I'd like to make it a generic method:

```
await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    switch (ModelType)
    {
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Certification:
            var listCerts = await dbContext.Certifications.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToListAsync();
            listModels.AddRange(listCerts.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
            PsuedoAttribute = listCerts.First();
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Interest:
            HasColors = true;
            var listInterests = await dbContext.Interests.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToListAsync();
            listModels.AddRange(listInterests.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
            PsuedoAttribute = listInterests.First();
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Skill:
            var listSkills = await dbContext.Skills.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToListAsync();
            listModels.AddRange(listSkills.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
            PsuedoAttribute = listSkills.First();
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Tag:
            var listTags = await dbContext.Tags.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToListAsync();
            listModels.AddRange(listTags.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
            PsuedoAttribute = listTags.First();
            break;
    }
}
```

What I can't figure it is how to make a generic of dbContext.Certifications, dbContext.Interests, etc. All 4 of those DbSets are model classes that inherit from the same base class. But they are distinct DbSets.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can use `dbContext.Set<YourEntityType>` to get a specific `DbSet`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I tried that - I think. What is the exact syntax for declaring it in the <> and then declaring the parameter? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this completely generic, you will need a couple of things.

First, tie all of your db items together with an interface:

```
public interface IAttributeModelItem
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Certification : IAttributeModelItem
{ ... 

public class Interest: IAttributeModelItem
{ ... 

// etc....
```

Use a nested function to make things generic + still have access to the scope

```
await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    switch (ModelType)
    {
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Certification:
            await ProcessDbItem<Certification>();
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Interest:
            HasColors = true;
            await ProcessDbItem<Interest>();
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Skill:
            .....
    }
    
    async Task ProcessDbItem<T>()
        where T : IAttributeModel 
    {
        var dbItems = await dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();

        // for this kind of query, go easy on your DB and sort after you query
        dbItems = dbItems.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        listModels.AddRange(dbItems.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
        PsuedoAttribute = dbItems.First();
    }
}
```

You could do this a ton of ways, but the takeaway is:

1. create a new method
2. make it generic
3. Use the `Set<T>()` method

Comment: The `Set<t>()` was the info I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used notepad so there may be errors but the meaning should be clear. There is no need for ToListAsync, ToArrayAsync should suffice.

```
await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    switch (ModelType)
    {
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Certification:
            await DoWork<Certificate>(dbContext , listModels , PsuedoAttribute);
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Interest:
            HasColors = true;
            await DoWork<Interest>(dbContext , listModels , PsuedoAttribute);
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Skill:
            await DoWork<Skill>(dbContext , listModels , PsuedoAttribute);
            break;
        case AttributeModel.AttributeType.Tag:
            await DoWork<Tag>(dbContext , listModels , PsuedoAttribute);
            break;
    }

    async Task DoWork<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext , List<AttributeModel> listModels , Object psuedoAttribute) 
            where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        TEntity[] items = await dbContext.Set<TEntity>().OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToArrayAsync();
        listModels.AddRange(items.Select(item => new AttributeModel(BlobService, item)));
        psuedoAttribute = items.First();
    }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    String Name {get;set;}
}
public class Certificate:IEntity
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
public class Interest:IEntity
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
public class Skill:IEntity
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
public class Tag:IEntity
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Literally the exact same answer as I had, even down to the quirks. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: @Shane Almost! I love micro optimizations, array is more optimal than List :)

Comment: emmmm, not really. On db read, ToArrayAsync will use a LargeArrayBuilder, which is functionally the same as a List, so no benefit there. Then on List (or Array) read, the JIT compiler has gotten really good at closing the gap here, where, if you do anything non trivial in your for loop, the performance gain of array is completely overshadowed

Comment: You are right, when I wrote I was thinking about ToArray, not ToArrayAsync. Sorry